# How do I unpack a Python requests.response object and extract string representations of its data?

Tags: python, python-requests

Edit: I did what I really wanted to do with the dir() method and extracting requests.response.text. I'll mark this as answered if that's allowed.

Let's say I download what's at a specific URL using `requests.get()` and assign it to a variable:

```
raw_object = requests.get(url)
```

So then I try this:

```
print(raw_object.CookieJar) // replace CookieJar with text
```

And the output is this string:

```
<requests.response.CookieJar>  // no longer correct; didn't know name of 
                               // attribute I wanted
```

While printing the return of the `type()` method with this attribute as a parameter only returns an object signature.

How can I get the data that's in that `CookieJar` attribute? Same with other `requests.response` object attributes.